# Inserting 'space' in an ASP.NET DropDownList Control

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an ASP.NET `DropDownList` control that retrieves the first and last name from a column in the database.  Instead of having just one space between the first and last name, I want there to be three.  How do I add the extra spaces between the two pieces of text in the `DropDownList`?

Comment: What is data source? are firstname and lastname comming from database table? is it a single column or two different coulmns in a table?

Comment: It's coming from a table in a database. It's a single column

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add **&nbsp;** instead of space character, and **HtmlDecode** all elements after binding :

```
string[] items = new string[] { 
    "name& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;surname1", 
    "name& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;surname2" };

ddl.DataSource = items;
ddl.DataBind();

foreach (ListItem item in ddl.Items)
{
    item.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I had this same question, thanks. I did however want to offer one suggestion.

If there's any chance you have an ampersand (&) or other special characters in your data, doing it this way is going to result in your name look like John &amp Jane instead of John & Jane.

So might be better to do it this way:

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("Fname" +HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;") +"Lname", id);
ddlSearchCategories.Items.Add(li);
```

Might want to use String.Format instead of +