# ASP.NET drowdownlist item text preceding blank space is not rendered

Tags: asp.net, listitem

I need to indent some dropdownlist item texts to right based upon a condition. For this I simply add blank space to the left of those item text, however they don't get rendered and the texts get trimmed. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Left padded certain texts right in the database (the dropdown list is populated from database)
2. `item.Text="   "+item.Text;`
3. `item.Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+item.Text;`

None of the above methods work. What is the proper way of doing this? I don't want to go CSS.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeJM/S8HWz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more a HTML then ASP.NET issue. In HTML spaces are trimmed between elements. The spec determined that 'non-significant' whitespace must be removed.

You have to use `&nbsp;` to make a 'significant' whitespace which will be rendered when at the start or end of an element.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question. In fact I'd mentioned that I had used &nbsp but stackoverflow trimmed it too. :))

Comment: @MikeJM: This this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8HWz/1/). This one is okay. I guess this is the thing we expect it to become. Your third sample becomes '&amp;nbsp;' so that looks like `" "` should work.

Comment: @MikeJM: See a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1422263/993547) to use &nbsp; and `HtmlDecode`.

Comment: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode is great. Thanks for guideance